# Updating database from change to select in table row

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a select box which is included in every row of a table - I would like to allow the user to change the value of that select box which triggers an update to MySQL without needing to reload the page etc

I have been able to get this to work using Ajax when there is one row but when they are multiple rows it breaks as jQuery cannot know which id or class I am referring to when more than one exists.

When a user changes the select in tr id 1 then I would like to pass the tr id into row and the selected stage into val so I can send it via Ajax to update (1,3 for example) and then if they update the select in row 2 it should send 2,1 for example.

HTML

```
<table>
<tr id="1">
<td>
<select name="dropdown" class="stage">
<option value="1">Stage 1</option>
<option value="2">Stage 2</option>
<option value="3">Stage 3</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
<td>
<select name="dropdown" class="stage">
<option value="1">Stage 1</option>
<option value="2">Stage 2</option>
<option value="3">Stage 3</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then in jQuery I am using:

```
$(document).on('change', '.stage',function(e)
{
    var row = $(".stage").parent("tr").attr("id");

    var val = $('.stage').val();
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(row);
    console.log(val);

    $.ajax({
        url:'updateStage.php',
        type:'post',
        data: {"row": row,"stage": val}
    });             

});
```

Then in updateStage.php I am getting the post value for row and val and updating MySQL - I haven't included that code as it works fine as long as I can get the correct values passed to it.

When I change the select, in console I see below:

```
undefined
3
```

This points to not getting the ID of the TR but also when I change the second select this doesn't always update to the correct value but takes the value of the first select instead.

Comment: you have to use `var row = $(this).parent("tr").attr("id");` and `$(this).val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
var row = $(".stage").parent("tr").attr("id");
```

to

```
var row = $(this).parents("tr").attr("id");
```

Comment: Excellent! This is what worked for me - now working, thanks

Comment: hello musicvicious, "If" is big thing.

Comment: @bhttoan  you should use `parents("tr:first")`

Comment: @RakeshSojitra if it is the right way then should i get my credits?

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML as below

```
<tr data-id="1">
<td>
<select name="dropdown" class="stage">
<option value="1">Stage 1</option>
<option value="2">Stage 2</option>
<option value="3">Stage 3</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr data-id="2">
<td>
<select name="dropdown" class="stage">
<option value="1">Stage 1</option>
<option value="2">Stage 2</option>
<option value="3">Stage 3</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Change your jQuery as below

```
var row = $(this).closest("tr").data("id");
```

Comment: Still getting undefined for row

Comment: @bhttoan have you noticed the change in `tr` i updated `id` value inside `data-id` and in `jQuery` changed `$('.stage')` to ` $(this)`

Comment: @bhttoan try my updated one. Instead of `parent()` try `closest()`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
//you are accessing current change element then use "this"
var row = $(this).parents("tr:first").attr("id");`
```

and

```
//var val = $('.stage').val();
var val = $(this).val();
```

Comment: I am still getting undefined for row

Answer (score 0):

`var row = $(".stage").parent("tr")` gives you the immediate parent.

What you actually want is

`var row = $(this).closest("tr").attr('id');`